# Proving discontinuity of $f(x) = \frac{x-2}{10}$ for $x \lt 0$ and $f(x) = x$ for $x \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble proving a function is discontinuous at the point c = 0 using the epsilon-delta definition.

$f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x-2}{10},& \text{if }x<0\\
x& \text{if } x ≥ 0 \end{cases}$

So I know I have to find an epsilon such that for all delta, there exists an x with $|x-c|<\delta \text{ and } |f(x)-f(0)|≥\epsilon$ but I'm not too sure how to go about it.

I started by considering $|f(x)-f(0)|$ but would I have to consider it for two separate cases; one where $x ≥ 0 \text{ and another where } x<0$?

Comment: If you take any $\delta>0$, then $f(\delta)-f(-\delta)>0.2$, so it cannot be continuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions are continuos on their domain but $x-2/10$ at 0 is $-\frac 15$ while $x$ is zero so pick $\epsilon<1/5$.

Then pick any $x<0$ then $|f(x)|=\frac{2-x}{10}>\frac 1 5$ and so of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that in some left neighborhood the values of the functions are less that $-\frac 1 {10}$, while the value in $0$ is $0$. So there's no such $\delta$ for $\varepsilon = \frac1 {100}$